# Virtual Directory Path in ASP.NET Core and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, virtual-directory

I've created a virtual directory in IIS, and I have a file that I want to get - like `example.pdf`. How do I get the virtual directory path and read the file in bytes? `server.MapPath` doesn't work in ASP.NET Core, and I didn't save the file in the `wwwroot`, I saved it to a folder `Uploads` outside the project, so I can't combine it with `ContentRootPath` or `WebRootPath`.

Can someone help me with this?

Currently my code is like this:

```
var path = "D:/FolderOutsideProjects/Uploads/filename.pdf";
var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);
return File(bytes, contentType, Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Thanks

Comment: I use AppContext.BaseDirectory (+folder+filename) which would be the folder where your dll/assembly runs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way for ASP.NET Core to resolve the Virtual Directory path. You could potentially read the IIS configuration file, but that seems very complicated.

The easy solution will just be adding your directory path to appsettings.json instead.